# Stop a bitmap when it collides with another bitmap

Tags: javascript, collision-detection, easeljs, createjs

I am currently learning CreateJS and am having an issue with a game I am working on.

I have the keyboard movement and impact detection figured out, but not what happens after the bitmaps collide.  Right now they just pass through each other, and the console logs the impact.  What I want to happen is that when the player (bitmap) hits the wall (bitmap), the player can no longer move in that direction anymore.

Can anyone help?

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var stage;  //Big, root level container for all display objects

//Assign the keycodes to readable variables
var KEYCODE_A = 65;
var KEYCODE_D = 68;
var KEYCODE_W = 87;
var KEYCODE_S = 83;

alphaThreshold = 1;

function init(){
    stage = new createjs.Stage("myCanvas");

    startGame();
}

function startGame(){
    //Load the bitmaps
    player = new createjs.Bitmap("assets/player-square.jpg");
    player.x = 10;
    player.y = 200;
    stage.addChild(player);

    mazeSquare = new createjs.Bitmap("assets/maze-test.png");
    mazeSquare.x = 250;
    mazeSquare.y = 0;
    stage.addChild(mazeSquare);

    //move the player, by listening to what key is pressed
    window.addEventListener('keydown', keyPressed, true);

    stage.update();
}

function keyPressed(event) {

    switch(event.keyCode) {
        case KEYCODE_W:
            //console.log("move up");
            if(player.y > 0){
                player.y -= 10;
                }
            break;  
        case KEYCODE_S:
            //console.log("move down");
            if(player.y < 430){  //stage height - square height
                player.y += 10;
                }
            break;
        case KEYCODE_A:
            //console.log("move left");
            if(player.x > 0){  //stage height - square height
                player.x -= 10;
                }
            break;
        case KEYCODE_D:
            //console.log("move right");
            if(player.x < 730){  //stage height - square height
                player.x += 10;
                }
            break;
    }

    //check for collisions after button press
    checkCollision();

    stage.update();
}

function checkCollision(keyPressed) {
    //Collision-Detection-for-EaselJS
    var intersection = ndgmr.checkPixelCollision(player, mazeSquare, alphaThreshold);

    //If the the intersection is not empty, that's because there was a collision.
      if (!intersection) {
         console.log("No Impact");

      } else {
          console.log("Impact");

      } //end else
}
</script>

</head>

<body onLoad="init();">

<center>
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="800" height="500" style="border: 1px solid #000000; background-image: url(assets/grass.png);">
Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas tag.
</canvas>
<br>
W  S  A  D - Moves the player
</center>
```

Comment: It's pretty simple: calculate the position the player *will* be in and check for collisions on that position *before* actually changing the position

Comment: That makes sense, but I am not sure how to do it.  Can you point me in the right direction about how to start?

Comment: I have a way of determining the location of the player after the keypress:    player.setBounds(player.x, player.y);
var playerBounds = player.getBounds();
console.log(playerBounds);       I can't seem to figure out how to use it to determine the location _before_ the button press.